# How to pass Jade string interpolation to JS script File?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have my Jade file like this:

```
script(text='text/javascript', src='/javascript/user_options.js')
    var firstName = #{firstnameDisplay};
```

My user_options.js:

```
var displayName = firstName;
```

I still get the 'firstName' variable as undefined. The string interpolation #{firstnameDisplay} in the Jade file is defined correctly. Any ideas or solutions? Is there a way to declare a JS variable in Jade and use it in the JS script file?

Other sources online recommended JSON, but I would prefer to just use Jade string interpolations.

Comment: Load the script after the var is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that... generate js code that way have a bunch of drawbacks. It is preferrable to put that value in a hidden field for example or as a data-attribute in some element then in your js file you could ask for that value.

**First Option**

```
input(type="hidden", value=#{firstnameDisplay}, id="firstNameDisplay")
```

**Second Option**

```
div(id="firstNameDisplay", data-firstNameDisplay=#{firstnameDisplay})
```

then you could retrieve that value with JQuery or Vanilla js.

```
var displayName = document.getElementById('firstNameDisplay').value
```

or

```
var displayName  = document.getElementById('firstNameDisplay').dataset.firstNameDisplay;
```

Comment: Would you let me know what kind of drawbacks it has?

Comment: No possibility of caching, bundling or minification. You should take great care with your js logic in order to not allow security risks because you are generating js code based on user input generally. For in depth research you could see [The Unexpected Dangers of Dynamic JavaScript](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity15/sec15-paper-lekies.pdf). I know your sample is simple and you could go safetly but it is important to know better alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this

```
script.
    var firstName = #{firstnameDisplay};

script(text='text/javascript', src='/javascript/user_options.js')
```